# H4 US visa expiration

Tags: visas, usa

I'm traveling to Pakistan on June 18 and will be back on July 27. I am on an H4 visa and my visa is going to expire on August 14. My husband is a cardiologist and has applied for premium H1 extension. Please could anyone let me know if there would be any problem entering the US or would they send me back due to having a visa which will expire in two weeks.

Comment: Is your husband's H1b extension going to be approved before you return?

Comment: HI Rohina, I'm having the same case as yours. So can you tell me wht did you do? did u go before your visa expiry date and did u face any problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can enter the US as long as your visa is valid, up until the day on which it expires.

https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/visa-expiration-date.html

> Sometimes understanding the difference between the visa expiration date and the length of time you have permission to remain in the United States can be confusing.
>
> [...]
>
> The visa expiration date is shown on the visa along with the visa issuance date. The time between visa issuance and expiration date is called your visa validity. **The visa validity is the length of time you are permitted to travel to a port of entry in the United States.**

(Emphasis added; hyphens removed.)

The broader point is that you do not need to have a valid visa *while you are in the US* because the US treats visa validity and immigration status as separate matters.  Once you're admitted to the US, your visa is essentially irrelevant; all that matters at that point is your immigration status.